# get output of query in source-edge-destination format

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to cypher. I am using the movie database of neo4j CE 3.1.2.
I want to get output of my query

```
match (a:Person)-[r]-(b:Movie) return a, r, b
```

in the form source, edge, destination, for example

> Tom Hanks, ACTED_IN, That Thing You Do
>
> Tom Hanks, DIRECTED, That Thing You Do
>
> Gary Sinise, ACTED_IN, The Green Mile

Basically I want a row for every source_node, destination_node connection.
Please help.

EDIT 1
If my graph is like A->B->C->D and if I want all down tree nodes of A, then my output should be like

> A,connected,B
>
> B,connected,C
>
> C,connected,D

[image: Sample Image of graph]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the graphical view of the results. If you look to the left of the graph, you'll see the ability to change to Row and Text views of the results, which should give you what you want...almost.

Output for relationships currently shows only properties on the relationships, not the type, so you may need to adjust your query slightly.

```
match (a:Person)-[r]-(b:Movie) 
return a, type(r) as type, b
```

If you want ONLY the person's name, the type of the relationship, and the movie title, then you'll need to return the properties from the nodes, not just the nodes themselves:

```
match (a:Person)-[r]-(b:Movie) 
return a.name as name, type(r) as type, b.title as title
```

Comment: This works when I don't specify a property of the source node. For eg, if I specify in my query that (a:Person{name:"Tom Hanks"}), then by this method I'll always get "Tom Hanks" in source node.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you specify the property name, then yes you'll get only that node as the source node. Can you better explain what inputs you want to take in, and the outputs you expect?

Comment: If my graph is like A->B->C->D and if I want all down tree nodes of A, then my output should be like

A,connected,B

B,connected,C

C,connected,D

Comment: Okay, can you add more detail to this request? Are there any restrictions on the relationship types on the path? Is there a limit to the number of traversals you want to do, or do you want to continue down until you reach a node without any outgoing relationships? Is your graph a tree or a connected graph like the movies graph?